# default parameters and compile time constants

Tags: .net, ado.net

Why is SqlInt32.Null not considered a compile-time constant? Because I cant use it as the default value of a default parameter.

Answer (score 5):

`SqlInt32.Null` is a `static readonly` field, not a constant. This means that its value may not be known at compile time.

The main difference between a `static readonly` field and a `const` is that the `const` can be initialized only in the declaration of it, while the `static readonly` field can be initialized in the declaration *or in a constructor*.

**Example:**

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public static readonly int SomeValue;

    static SomeClass()
    {
        SomeValue = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
    }
}
```

In the example above a `static readonly` field is initialized by the static constructor in a way that illuminates why it cannot be determined at compile time.